# How to read object's DependencyProperty in code?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, event-handling, dependency-properties

In my XAML I have an object with `DependencyProperty`:

`<TextBlock local:Extensions.OverWidth="100"/>`

I also have `MouseUp` handler upon this `TextBlock`. How do I get `OverWidth` property value in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That seems to be an [attached property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which should have static getter and setter methods:

```
private void TextBlock_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var textBlock = (TextBlock)sender;
    var overWidth = Extensions.GetOverWidth(textBlock);
    ...
}
```